# One xelement and multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, namespaces

Recently, I have been working with a document using two namespaces. I have been able to create multiple XElements that use the different namespaces, such as has been answered here:
[How to load and add elements in an XML tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094878/how-to-load-and-add-elements-in-an-xml-tree)

The problem, is I need to combine the two dc and opf namespaces in the same element and I cannot figure out how to do that. I use this code to create an XML element:

```
//open the opf file as an LINQ XML document.
XDocument opfDoc = XDocument.Load(opfFile);

//create the xmlnamespaces required for the <metadata> section of the opf file.
var dc = (XNamespace)"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
var opf = (XNamespace)"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf";

//**add book metadata
meta.Add(new XElement(dc + "creator", bookCreators[0].bookCreator));
```

The output looks like this:

```
<dc:creator>Author Name</dc:creator>
```

What I need to do is to add one or more additional attributes that use another namespace, so the code outputs this:

```
<dc:creator opf:file-as="Name, Author">Author Name</dc:creator>
```

I tried writing this code...

```
    meta.Add(new XElement(dc + "creator", 
        new XmlAttribute(opf + "file-as", bookCreators[0].bookCreatorFileAs),
        bookCreators[0].bookCreator));
```

... But I keep receiving this error message:

> xattribute does not contain a constructor that takes two arguments

Can you recommend an approach to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: For one thing you are confusing XAttribute and XmlAttribute. Fixing that might just solve your issue.

Comment: You are correct. I mistakenly added XmlAttribute instead of XAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

As Henk pointed out, I was using XMLAttribute instead of XAttribute. Once I did this, I got what I needed. Here is the code that works:

```
    meta.Add(new XElement(dc + "creator", 
        new XAttribute(opf+ "role", "aut"),
        new XAttribute(opf+ "file-as",bookCreators[0].bookCreatorFileAs),
        bookCreators[0].bookCreator));
```